# Start a for loop

Tags: for-loop, initialization

Another infantile question from me, but I dare to ask it.

The code is the foolowing:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Exercise25

{
    public static void Main()

    {
        Console.WriteLine("Define the values!");
        int[] arr = new int [3];
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {

            Console.Write("Number {0} : ", i);
            arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        int sum = arr.Sum();
        double ave = arr.Average();
        Console.WriteLine("The average is: {0}\nThe sum of the values is {1}\n", ave, sum);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

My goal is, that when the program writes which number it is asking for

```
(Console.Write("Number {0} : ", i);
```

It should ask for Number 1 as the first number, not number 0.
I inatialized 'i' with 1 up to "<4" or "<=3" or "<=4", but then it wouldn't work.

Of course it still needs to ask for 3 numbers. When I didn't define the size of the array when creating, I also got error code.

I'm sure the solution is easy, and sorry for taking your time, but I'm stuck with it, I tried everything I could think of. Thanks.

Comment: *"but then it wouldn't work"* - It sounds like you have some code which is *different from* what you're showing us, and it failing *in some describable way*.  If that's the error you're trying to solve, perhaps you could focus on that?  Normally "How do I do X?" is answered with "By writing code to do that."  How did you try to solve your problem?  What code did you write?  In what way did it not work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it didn't work when you initialized i as 1 and incremented it up to 3 is because you can't define an array[3] when the index 3 doesn't exist (only 0, 1, and 2 do because you initialized it as length 3) . Simply replace

```
Console.Write("Number {0} : ", i);
```

with

```
Console.Write("Number {0} : ", (i+1));
```

This will not change the index you are writing to, but it will display what you want it to.